# Как запустить мой сайт на Angular в Nginx

Tags: nginx, angular

Создал простое Angular приложение, буквально одна страничка с меню и несколькими полями.
Пробую запустить в IDEA - все работает.
Теперь хочу запустить этот сайт в Nginx.
Собираю проект

```
ng build --prod
```

копирую его в папку mysite на сервер
добавляю в файл nginx.conf

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  mysite;
        location / {
            root   ../mysite;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
}
```

добавляю в файл hosts строку

```
127.0.0.1       mysite
```

набираю в браузере

```
http://mysite
```

и не находит он моего сайта.

```
404 Not Found
```

Что я делаю не так? Может я в файле hosts что-то не то прописываю или его вообще не надо трогать?

Comment: возможно стоит указывать абсолютный путь к папке `mysite`, а не относительный

Comment: Заменил на "root   C:\Development\nginx\mysite" - не помогло.

Comment: попробовал, не помогает. Я уже попробовал поменять на root html; как в основных настройках, и все равно по моей ссылке ни чего не открывается

Comment: а почему root должен быть выше location, если в самой документации на nginx он во всех примерах находится в location?

Answer (score 0):

У ангуляра свой роутер, поэтому все ссылки должны указывать на index.html

```
server {
   listen       80;
   server_name  mysite;
   root /usr/share/nginx/html; #путь к билду вашего проекта
   location / {
      try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
   }
}
```